# runforms.jsp request from CodeGenerationLog.txt not found the the script

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, correlation, loadrunner

After recording an Oracle application LoadRunner script, this runform.jsp request is not found in the Action.c code, however it's showing in the CodeGenerationLog.txt file, any idea why it is not generated after recording? 
The reason to locate that request code is because there is a fsst value that need to be correlated

Here's the attributes used -

Protocol - OracleNCA + Web HTTP/HTML
VuGen version -  v12.01 Build 2079
Java version - 1.8.1_101
FireFox ESR - 45.3.01
Oracle Form Version : 12.0.306.12020000.72

Have tried - DEP disabled, Anti-Virus disabled, Both HTML and URL-based recording

Any comment/advise would be very appreciated. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

- Is this located at a third party site which you have filtered from your recording?
- If you save a separate copy of the recording and regenerate in URL mode with individual requests will you observe a copy of the call that you can then copy and paste into your own code?
- As you can see this call in the generation log, why can you not just copy and place it in the appropriate location in your test code/script?  QED: Fixed.  File a defect with HP and move forward

Comment: James, thanks for prompt reply.

To reply your questions - 
1, I'm doing recording on client side with direct connection. so I don't filter any from recording, question is - is there any I can tweak in recording options, that might filter any from my recording?

Comment: Examine your recording settings for any filters which have been set.  Be pragmatic: Just copy the generated request to its proper location since it is in the generation log.  File the defect with HP that it didn't show up.

Comment: 2. I did tried both HTML/URL based script but still can locate that runforms.jsp request in the action.c 
3. can you provide more details on how to copy/paste code needed in the script?

Thanks

Comment: yes, I have HPE case opened, but it seems like not helping at this moment, I escalated to HPE

Comment: Assuming you have the generated request in the code generation log then you just copy the generated snippet to the proper location in the Action.c.   Otherwise, use either a web_url() or web_custom_request() statement and code the request by hand leveraging your foundation skills in programming.

Comment: By following your direction, now I can get the fsst_1 value from response of runforms.jsp. But now it fails at fsvt not found at next request. I will update once I figure this out.